# How do I put an image on items of ListView and change it dynamically?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm trying to make a color picker in QML. The color details are stored in a ListModel and I've tried to create a horizontal row of colors to choose from.
Something like this:
[image: Snapshot]

The problem is, I'm unable to add a button image over the selected cell. I want to highlight the cell the user has selected by placing an image at the center of that cell.
The following is the code snippet I've written

```
ListView{
    id: list
    height: 30
    width: 500

    anchors.bottom: main.bottom
    anchors.horizontalCenter: main.horizontalCenter
    anchors.bottomMargin: 40

    orientation: ListView.Horizontal

    model: myModel
    delegate:
        Item {
        id: cell
        property alias cellColor: rectangle.color
        signal clicked(color cellColor)

        width: 500/myModel.count; height: 25

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            color: clr
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        onClicked:{
            dynamicRect.color=cellColor
            list.currentIndex=index
            console.log(list.currentIndex)
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            z: 1
            onClicked: {
                cell.clicked(cell.cellColor)
            }
        }
    }

    highlight:
        Image {
        id: button
        height: 20
        width: 20
        source: "button.png"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: list.currentItem.horizontalCenter
    }

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could there be a problem with z-indexing here?

Comment: I've tried inserting z indexing in MouseArea as well. No luck !

Comment: I meant z-indexing between the dynamicRect and the image you are using in your delegate. Perhaps you could expand on the provided code?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the image directly into the highlight, i mean, without the Component definition ? Also, posting the code instead of an image would help by allowing to experiment without having to do OCR :)

Comment: Hey,I've put in the code now, instead of an image.

Comment: Change the z index of the highlight button image not the mousearea.